# Marquee without Space

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I have a marquee that is scrolling upwards.

```
<marquee scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="0" direction="up">
Element One<br/>
Element Two<br/>
...
Element Five Hundred and Thrty-Seven <!-- ;) -->
</marquee>
```

Now, what I want, is to achieve that, when the elements end, there is no space until the last element is no longer displayed, but the list starts from the beginning immediately. I would also like the marquee not to first scroll upwards and let the first elements appear one by one, but start having the first element already scrolled to the top and then just go on scrolling. The former thing I have mentioned I need to achieve is by far more important than the latter. I don't mind if the solution involves not making it a marquee but some div with scrolling or stuff like that. Only, please do not post JQuery results but pure JavaScript.

There has been such a question about a marquee without a gap asked already, but the answer involved duplicating the text, which however, though removing the first gap, still leaves the second one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<marquee>`, mysterious no jQuery comment... Old fashioned, a bit, are we?

Comment: ^^ I do not actually want to use the marquee tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without trying to be rude, might I suggest that you probably oughtn't use a marquee tag?

See this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) for a breakdown of the usability problems.

A better approach would be to use javascript to progressively enhance the page. Here's an [example in jQuery](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/).

Comment: well, as I have said, I do not actually want to use it. All I need is to get rid of the gap, which this marquee example does not offer.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">

.container-marquee{
position: relative;
width:100%; /*marquee width */
height: 200px; /*marquee height */
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Simple Marquee (04-October-2012)
* by Vic Phillips - http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk/
***********************************************/

var zxcMarquee={

 init:function(o){
  var mde=o.Mode,mde=typeof(mde)=='string'&&mde.charAt(0).toUpperCase()=='H'?['left','offsetWidth','top','width']:['top','offsetHeight','left','height'],id=o.ID,srt=o.StartDelay,ud=o.StartDirection,p=document.getElementById(id),obj=p.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0],sz=obj[mde[1]],clone;
  p.style.overflow='hidden';
  obj.style.position='absolute';
  obj.style[mde[0]]='0px';
  obj.style[mde[3]]=sz+'px';
  clone=obj.cloneNode(true);
  clone.style[mde[0]]=sz+'px';
  clone.style[mde[2]]='0px';
  obj.appendChild(clone);
  o=this['zxc'+id]={
   obj:obj,
   mde:mde[0],
   sz:sz
  }
  if (typeof(srt)=='number'){
   o.dly=setTimeout(function(){ zxcMarquee.scroll(id,typeof(ud)=='number'?ud:-1); },srt);
  }
  else {
   this.scroll(id,0)
  }
 },

 scroll:function(id,ud){
  var oop=this,o=this['zxc'+id],p;
  if (o){
   ud=typeof(ud)=='number'?ud:0;
   clearTimeout(o.dly);
   p=parseInt(o.obj.style[o.mde])+ud;
   if ((ud>0&&p>0)||(ud<0&&p<-o.sz)){
    p+=o.sz*(ud>0?-1:1);
   }
   o.obj.style[o.mde]=p+'px';
   o.dly=setTimeout(function(){ oop.scroll(id,ud); },50);
  }
 }
}

function init(){

 zxcMarquee.init({
  ID:'marquee1',     // the unique ID name of the parent DIV.                        (string)
  Mode:'Horizontal',   //(optional) the mode of execution, 'Vertical' or 'Horizontal'. (string, default = 'Vertical')
  StartDelay:2000,   //(optional) the auto start delay in milli seconds'.            (number, default = no auto start)
  StartDirection:-1  //(optional) the auto start scroll direction'.                  (number, default = -1)
 });


}

if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", init, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", init)
else if (document.getElementById)
 window.onload=init


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="marquee1" class="container-marquee" onmouseover="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee1',0);" onmouseout="zxcMarquee.scroll('marquee1',-1);">
<div style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">
Excel in your CA Final exams! Seminars on Robomate CA at Belgaum on 12th Jan., at Mysore on 19th Jan. & Bangalore on 26th Jan. Register now by calling 1800267662!
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```